# SQL Find a Value in a Table With Max Value (Result must be editable)

Tags: sql, sql-server, max

so im stuck on this, seems like, simple problem.

I have a table with some Informations

| ID | Other ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 100 |
| 2 | 214 |
| 1 | 1156 |
| 3 | 1252 |
| 4 |  |
| 1 | 240 |

I now only want the rows with the highest value in in an editable query
Like:

```
| ID       | Other ID           |
| -------- | -------------- |
| 2        | 214    |
| 1        | 1156            |
| 3        | 1252            |
| 4        |           |
```

But it has to be editable so i can change some other values in this Table.

I Tried to create a query where all Max(Date), ID are and combine them with a JOIN. But this makes the query uneditable

I hope i described my problem well enough to understand... Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

The simplest method is to use `row_number()`:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by id
                                order by otherid desc
                               ) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Happily, SQL treats `NULL` values as smaller than any other value for sorting purposes, so the descending `order by` puts them last.

Answer (score 0):

```
ID  OTHER ID
1   100
2   214
1   1156
3   1252
4   
1   240


create table find_max(id number(2),other_id number(10));

insert into find_max values(1,100);
insert into find_max values(2,214);
insert into find_max values(1,1156);
insert into find_max values(3,1252);
insert into find_max values(4,null);
insert into find_max values(1,240);
commit;

with d as(
select * from find_max),
 d2 as(select d.*,dense_rank() over(partition by id order by other_id desc nulls last) r from d
where id =1)
select * from d2
where r=:r;
```